# Proper way of handling display error on Kali Linux + ATI Radeon

Tags: kali-linux, graphics, radeon, ati

I've installed a fresh copy of [latest Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) onto my HDD. Booting it up for the first time, after the grub loaded I got a [well](https://thehacktoday.com/fix-kali-black-screen-after-grub-boot-up/)-[known](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842) [issue](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?32118-Grey-Login-screen-that-fails-to-transition-to-GUI-and-reboots-On-HD-install-only)
 of greyish screen with fuzzy lines that appear to be the login screen. You can type and log in and click things and see those lines change as well, but it's basically inoperative.

Workaround is to edit startup grub script, adding `nomodeset` and `grub_gfxmode=1024x768x24` (resolution according to your `vbeinfo`). Then system loads and looks correct and you are able to fix it installing your drivers or doing some configuration. Myself, I performed `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` immediately after login.

Now, is it healthy to just edit the grub default file permanently, because it actually works? What are threats of such a way? What looks interesting to me, is that my resolution is actually 1400x1050 (preferred by the system and me) instead of 1024x768 that I set in grub. And when I try to change the resolution through settings' Display menu, I get a different one indeed, but with fuzzy-rainbow colours everywhere. That doesn't look like it should work this way, but I don't really plan on changing this ever.

I'm running quite an old gear, that might be unsupported:
Lenovo ThinkPad T60 + 4GB RAM + ATI Radeon X1400.